# Adding blog to specific page using Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms

I need to add existing blog to page. How I can do that?
I have page with layout and I need to add blog with pagination for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a query with for content type blog posts as a filter and then you can add a projection widget based on this query to your page layout.

Comment: Thanks, it helped)